# Is it possible to choose and clear all options availiable in Tokenize2?

Tags: tokenize2

I wanna add buttons "Choose all" and "Remove all" for the Tokenize2, to be able to past at once all possible options or to remove all at once . Is it possible? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to clear all :

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tokenizeSelectClass').trigger('tokenize:clear');

});
```

I have managed to check all :

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tokenizeSelectClass options').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('.tokenizeSelectClass').trigger('tokenize:remap');

});
```